# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool error when my Python script finds some website offline

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get this error when my Python script finds some website offline:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool
```

Code:

```
# *- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import os.path


def download_url(url):
  print("downloading: ",url)

  file_name_start_pos = url.rfind(".txt") + 1
  file_name = url[file_name_start_pos:]
 
  r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
  if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    if not os.path.isfile("data_file.txt"):
      file=open("data_file.txt","w")
      file.close()
    
    with open("data_file.txt", 'ab') as f:
      f.write(bytes("\n\n----------- "+file_name+" -----------\n\n",'utf-8'))
      for data in r:
        f.write(data)

download_url("https://wordpress.org/plugins/readme.txt")
download_url("https://wolfstudios.nl/readme.txt")
download_url("http://download.ni.com/support/softlib/visa/NI-VISA/17.0/Linux/README.txt")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a remote site is unreachable you can just catch the network error in a better way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# *- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import os.path
import sys

def download_url(url):
    print("downloading: ", url)

    file_name_start_pos = url.rfind(".txt") + 1
    file_name = url[file_name_start_pos:]

    try:
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            with open("data_file.txt", 'ab') as f:
                f.write(bytes("\n\n----------- "+file_name+" -----------\n\n",'utf-8'))
                for data in r:
                    f.write(data)
    except Exception as e:
        sys.stderr.write("Error while downloading {}: {}\n".format(url, e))

download_url("https://wordpress.org/plugins/readme.txt")
download_url("https://wolfstudios.nl/readme.txt")
download_url("http://download.ni.com/support/softlib/visa/NI-VISA/17.0/Linux/README.txt")
```

or retry the download as explained [here](https://gist.github.com/peketamin/61afdf90899713304f3978aafd73a8ae).